# java.lang.IllegalStateException: sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType) must not be null in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have build a flutter app which has features like showing qibla direction with the help of flutter_compass dependencies. This App works fine in newest versions of Android Devices but if i try to install this app in older versions (API 16, API 17) it shows "Unfortunately this App has Stopped". I checked in logcat it shows "java.lang.IllegalStateException: sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType) must not be null". So do i need to add some native code in android folder or dependencies in buildgradle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, the flutter_compass plugin uses the `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor type to gain access to the compass sensor. This value was added in Android SDK 20, (Android 4.4, KitKat). Because of that, this plugin is not going to work on Android versions prior to KitKat.

As such, your options are to either file an issue on the plugin's [github page](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_compass/issues) or to try and recreate the functionality yourself on the native side with a fix for pre-KitKat versions of Android.